# How to access the dynamic values of a set of sliders?

Tags: slider

I'm using a dynamic number of sliders and I want to access the current values of them. The values can be seen on the labels. However, I want them to be stored into an array. Below is what I have done so far:

```
 Manipulate[
  s = ConstantArray[0.5, n]; 
 Dynamic@Column[{Grid[
 Table[{"Slider "[i], 
   Slider[s[[i]], Appearance -> "Labeled"]}, {i, 1, n, 1}]]}], {n,
 2, 10, 1}]
```

Clearly, the initial values are stored in $s$ and I want the values to be updated dynamically.

Comment: ~~ `Table[With[{i=i}, ...Slider[Dynamic[s[[i]] ],...]...` See documentation of `Slider`.

Comment: See [A Good Trick to Know](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html#2125133640).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh! I looked at that page earlier. But I just overlooked that specific portion. Thanks to both of you(@Kuba, @MichaelE2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps not ***easy*** to find in the documentation, but answered clearly in the section called [A Good Trick to Know](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html#2125133640) in the tutorial, "An Introduction to Dynamic":

> This can be done with `/.` or with the somewhat peculiar but convenient idiomatic form demonstrated here.
>
> ```
> Table[With[{i = i}, Slider[Dynamic[data[[i]]]]], {i, 5}]
> ```
>
> This output shows that Dynamic does in fact work perfectly with part extraction syntax, a very useful property.

Comment: on what way to do the same  using `/.` ?

Comment: @Dragutin Something like `Table[Slider[Dynamic[data[[i]]] /. HoldPattern[i] -> i], {i, 5}]`